# Changes in imported less files don't trigger re-compilation

Tags: playframework, sbt, less

I have the following in my build:

```
includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"

excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "_*.less"
```

And in one of my entrypoint less files, say `page.less`, i have:

```
@import "../inc/_shared.less";
```

at the top.

Changes in `page.less` trigger a re-compilation (as it should), but changes in `_shared.less` don't.

I think it's because of the excludeFilter above.

Is there a way I can have the included files NOT be entrypoints, but still have changes to them trigger a re-compilation of the relevant entrypoint files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was already filed as a bug:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-less/issues/72

And fixed in sbt-less version 1.1.1